# Payment option in Webview?

Tags: android, url, webview

I am new to android.

In my app I have an payment option.

To pay the money I have a link.

**Can I call the link in Webview?** 
( or )
**I need to call the url in external browser?**

Can anyone please help me to find the solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no basic research is done before asking the question

Comment: Hi, I have researched before asking this question.  I didn't get any related question regards on-line payment in android web-view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its depends on your app requirement. If you want control remains with your app then use webview and pass link to it otherwise pass url to external browser.

Comment: Thank you for your response and also for the answer :)